# What String should fit on the RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory 'typeFieldName' when deserializing a JSON?

Tags: java, json, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize this JSON:

```
{
  "locations":
  [
    {
      "name": "Sagrada Família",
      "coordinates": [2.174400, 41.403475],
      "description": "Famosa església inacabada iniciada la dècada de 1880, amb un museu i vistes de la ciutat.",
      "architect": "Antoni Gaudí i Cornet",
      "inauguration": 2026
    },
    {
      "name": "Plaça Catalunya",
      "coordinates": [2.170079, 41.386878],
      "description": "La plaça de Catalunya és la més cèntrica i gran de les places de Barcelona. Constitueix el punt d'unió \nentre el nucli antic de la ciutat i l'Eixample. D'aquí parteixen importants vies de la ciutat com la Rambla, \nel passeig de Gràcia, la rambla de Catalunya, les rondes de la Universitat i de Sant Pere i el carrer Pelai, \nigual com l'avinguda del Portal de l'Àngel, la gran artèria comercial de la ciutat, i antiga porta de \nles muralles."
    },
    {
      "name": "Can Punyetes",
      "coordinates": [2.159704, 41.398694],
      "description": "Restaurant de cuina catalana.",
      "characteristics": ["Acollidor", "Informal", "Està bé per als nens"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Traphouse",
      "coordinates": [2.165150, 41.405290],
      "description": "Casa reconeguda principalment per les cançons que es composen aquí. Els veïns són una delícia, \nmai es queixen del xivarri que hi ha."
    },
    {
      "name": "Lloc de Socis",
      "coordinates": [2.166506, 41.402617],
      "description": "Si alguna vegada vols ser soci d'un club on la gent s'ho passa molt bé, aquest és el lloc \non has d'anar. No te'n penediràs!"
    },
    {
      "name": "Adoquín Square",
      "coordinates": [2.172804, 41.388794],
      "description": "Plaça coneguda pels jocs lúdics que s'organitzen. Es poden fer des de partides de Minecraft fins al \njoc de la manguera d'aigua. També s'ofereix servei de barbacoa."
    },
{
      "name":"Hotel W",
      "coordinates": [2.190109, 41.368762],
      "description": "Hotel més famós de Barcelona definit per la seva forma de vela. A dins t'hi pots trobar de tot\n menys Barcelonins. Ha estat galardonat amb el premi per més mites per metre quadrat de la ciutat, \nprecedit per La Salle Campus Barcelona",
      "stars": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

The JSON consist of an array of object `Location` but I also want to store data in sub-classes of `Location`. This are all the classes:

```
public class Location {

    private String name;
    private double[] coordinates;
    private String description;
}

public class Hotel extends Location {

    private short stars;
}

public class Monument extends Location {

    private String architect;
    private short inauguration;
}

public class Restaurant extends Location {

    private String[] characteristics;
}

public class DataModel {      //Class that will contain the JSON data

    private Location[] locations;
}
```

To deserialize this polymorphic JSON I'm doing this:

```
try {
            RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Location> runtimeTypeAdapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
                                                                    .of(Location.class, "type")
                                                                    .registerSubtype(Hotel.class)
                                                                    .registerSubtype(Monument.class)
                                                                    .registerSubtype(Restaurant.class);
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(runtimeTypeAdapterFactory).create();
            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(path));
            dataModel = gson.fromJson(reader, DataModel.class);
            int i= 0;

        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
        }
```

But the output I get is:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonParseException: cannot deserialize class models.Location because it does not define a field named type

I've also tried changing the label "type" to "locations" as shown on the JSON but with any success. What is wrong or missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/47b28d99a17d492b37fcdd0fc41290419a010a0f/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) of `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`:

> Create a {@code RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory} by passing the base type and type field
>    name to the {@link #of} factory method. If you don't supply an explicit type
>    field name, {@code "type"} will be used.

Each element of your json should have a field denoting the class name of that element.

For eg,

```
    {
      "name": "Adoquín Square",
      "coordinates": [
        2.172804,
        41.388794
      ],
      "description": "Plaça coneguda pels jocs lúdics que s'organitzen. Es poden fer des de partides de Minecraft fins al \njoc de la manguera d'aigua. També s'ofereix servei de barbacoa.",
      "type": "Location"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hotel W",
      "coordinates": [
        2.190109,
        41.368762
      ],
      "description": "Hotel més famós de Barcelona definit per la seva forma de vela. A dins t'hi pots trobar de tot\n menys Barcelonins. Ha estat galardonat amb el premi per més mites per metre quadrat de la ciutat, \nprecedit per La Salle Campus Barcelona",
      "stars": 5,
      "type": "Hotel"
    }
```